# What should max() return for empty lists?

Tags: scala

Got `java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list` so I tried to check for that. But now I get `[info] - max of a few numbers *** FAILED ***
[info]   0 did not equal 7 (ListsSuite.scala:128)`

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  if xs.isEmpty 0 // What can I do? 
  else if (xs.head > max(xs.tail)) max(xs.tail)
  else max(xs.tail)
}
```

edit:

1. The test case failed because my test was wrong.
2. For my [class](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004)mates, a reminder of the Coursera honor code:

   - I will register for only one account. My answers to homework, quizzes
     and exams will be my own work (except for assignments that explicitly
     permit collaboration).
   - I will not make solutions to homework, quizzes
     or exams available to anyone else. This includes both solutions
     written by me, as well as any official solutions provided by the
     course staff.
   - I will not engage in any other activities that will
     dishonestly improve my results or dishonestly improve/hurt the
     results of others.

Comment: This is from the Coursera FP course, I assume (since I'm doing that too and the names are suggestive). You're not supposed to be getting help from places like SO, I would suggest

Comment: I didn't see anything about that in the honor code. Plus I really learned a ton from the 3 answers below and all the comments. I actually did not use any of the suggested solutions as the function needs to return an Integer. Do correct me if I am wrong! I did read "I will not make solutions to homework, quizzes or exams available to anyone else" Could I ask something like this in the Coursera forums and be ok? I don't think we even get points for this initial assignment, do we?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but "My answers to homework, quizzes and exams will be my own work (except for assignments that explicitly permit collaboration)." and "I will not engage in any other activities that will dishonestly improve my results " would seem to cover asking someone else what should happen for edge conditions of a function you've been asked to write. However, as you say, no marks for this one.

Comment: No, you are right, @Paul. "except for assignments that explicitly permit collaboration" is pretty clear. My bad. I would like to keep this post up though as I do believe the answers and discussion add value to the SO site. Also, this small comment thread (for people taking the course searching for answers on assignment 1) is enlightening. And by the way, do you think they intend for us to modify function return types?

Comment: "do you think they intend for us to modify function return types? " Not for this assignment. Also it would mess up the automated tests, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, you can't return anything but `None` because an empty sequence in general has no meaningful default max value. That, however, is not necessarily the case all the time; for example you might want to find the maximum salary in a list of people, in which case it would make sense to say it's 0 if the list is empty; however, there is no trivial way to implement such default value logic generically (you'd have to use stuff like type classes and wrapped values); your best bet now is to simply use `Option[Int]`:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Option[Int] = xs match {
  case Nil => None
  case x :: Nil => Some(x)
  case x :: xs => Some(x max max(xs))
}
```

Then, you can easily fall back to a default value at the call site:

```
val posOrNeg = List(-5, -2, 1, 4, 10)
max(posOrNeg) // => Some(10)
val posOrNeg = List.empty[Int]
max(posOrNeg) // => None

val onlyPos = List(1, 2, 3)
max(onlyPos).getOrElse(0) // => 3
val onlyPos = List.empty[Int]
max(onlyPos).getOrElse(0) // => 0
```

**Bonus:** Also, you can make your `max` work on any list of numeric values:

```
def max[T: Numeric](xs: List[T]): Option[T] = xs match {
  case Nil => None
  case x :: Nil => Some(x)
  case x :: xs => Some(x max max(xs))
}
```

or in fact any suitable data structure made up of numeric values by using a type more general than `List`, but I'll leave that up to you.

**But keep in mind:** no matter which solution you opt for, always try to avoid `try` and exceptions in general — exceptions are not in the spirit of idiomatic functional programming (even though even some library functions use them occasionally for various reasons).

Comment: Note: `Numeric` has a `zero` method, so you still return `T` instead of `Option[T]` by returning `implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero` instead of `None`

Comment: @Dylan: but that is not necessarily correct/desirable — how about when the list can contain negative values?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **Option**.

```
def max(xs: List[Int]) = 
  if xs.isEmpty None
  else if (xs.head > max(xs.tail)) Some( max(xs.tail) )
  else Some( max(xs.tail))
```

The Option-Monad can either be *Some( result )*, meaning there is a result or *None*, meaning there is no result. If you wrap something in *Some* you say it's is a result and everything is fine.

As an alternative you solution you could wrap everything in a **Try** which would be the best because an empty list has no max and it's the right thing to get an error for that but now you can handle it in a functional way.

```
def max(xs: List[Int]) = Try( if (xs.head > max(xs.tail)) max(xs.tail) else xs.tail )
```

Comment: If you remove the `Try` alternative, I'll +1 :)

Comment: @Erik Allik I think it's important to choose for oneself which solution fits the problem and as I have been tainted with the dark arts of Perl I believe there is alway more than one way to do it, depending on the problem you have to solve ;)

Comment: Just because there are many ways to do something doesn't mean all ways are equally good; using exceptions where you don't need to is *not* considered good style in FP (nor actually in any other paradigm).

Comment: Could you explain what the Some() function does?

Comment: @broinjc: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: Added a short explantion for Some()

Comment: @AndreasNeumann Thank you. Now I need to look up monads. I am brand new to this functional world :]. I should have rephrased my question to "teach me everything to know about scala"

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense to define a max element for an empty collection, so you should either return a sentinel value, or throw an exception (e.g. IllegalArgumentException).

Also, you should make a few changes to your code (if you want to implement it yourself, and not use the built-in stuff):

```
def max(list: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    list match {
        // List has no elements, so we return None
        case Nil => None
        // Only one element, that is the maximum
        case x :: Nil => Some(x)
        // Compute max(list.tail). 
        // If defined, it will return the greater of list.tail and list.head
        case head :: tail => max(tail).map(_ max head)
    }
}
```

Comment: The sentinel value is `None`, and exceptions are almost *never* preferred in functional programming and thus Scala; also, I see nothing wrong with calling `max` on a potentially empty sequence — why would you think it's wrong? In some cases, it can even be a value (instead of `None`) such as for a list of positive integers where the result could be 0.

Comment: @ErikAllik `TraversableOnce.max` says `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.max")`.

Comment: @som-snytt: yeah, that's unfortunate; must be a bad design choice they are now regretting :P (or it possibly happened for performance reasons)

Comment: What do you mean by "if you want to implement it yourself, and not use the built-in stuff"? I should use that case syntax and not if else statements?

Comment: I was referring to e.g. `List(1, 2, 3).max` which already does what more or less.

Comment: @broinjc As Erik pointed out, you can use the built-in `max`. Pattern matching is something very powerful and sweet to use in Scala, and a great alternative to some `if-else`s you'll write.

Comment: `Nil == List() == List.empty`